# CORS in a restify server is giving me trouble

Tags: node.js, cors, restify

I have a RESTIFY api up and running on a Raspberry pi. It's IP is static at `192.168.1.12`. I also want to run a web server from `create-react-app` that I can access that grabs information from the api.

- RESTify - 192.168.1.12:8080
- create-react-app: 192.168.1.12:3000

`create-react-app`:

```
axios.get(`http://localhost:8080/ping`).then(
    (response) => {
        console.log(`response received!`);
    }
).catch(
    (error) => {
        console.error(`error received from axios`);
    }
);
```

`RESTify` (when setting up the server):

```
const corsMiddleware = require('restify-cors-middleware');
const cors = corsMiddleware(
    {
        origins: [
            '*'
        ]
    }
);
server.pre(cors.preflight);
server.use(cors.actual);
server.get(`/ping`, (req, res) => res.send(200));
```

Yet I still cannot get the `create-react-app` to get through to the server. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Expressjs then You can use.

```
npm install cors
var express = require('express')
var cors = require('cors')
var app = express()

app.use(cors())
```

Or You can use middleware

```
//CORS middleware
var corsMiddleware = function(req, res, next) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'localhost'); //replace localhost with actual host
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET, PUT, PATCH, POST, DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, X-Requested-With, Authorization');

    next();
}

app.use(corsMiddleware);
```

Comment: I'm going to use `pm2` to just run my `create-react-app`, no express. My `restify` server is already up and developed so I cannot switch to express. I've tried your second option and that did not work.

Comment: res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'localhost'); //replace localhost with actual host
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET, PUT, PATCH, POST, DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, X-Requested-With, Authorization');

Comment: What is your backend?

Comment: I've tried you're second option (setting headers) and I've had the same result.

Comment: Running a restify server using yarn that runs on boot using systemd. Would also like to run a front-end (hence create-react-app) which also runs on boot with systemd and yarn. all internal

Comment: You can set header in any language try second one.

Comment: I have tried the second one. I mentioned that in my last two comments.

Comment: You can temporary solve this issue by a chrome plugin called CORS.

Comment: I can't use a plugin - I'm trying to create a front-end for my phone (iOS) and cannot install plugins there.

Answer (score 0):

```
 res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'localhost'); //replace localhost with actual host
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET, PUT, PATCH, POST, DELETE');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, X-Requested-With, Authorization');
```

Answer (score 0):

`restify on port 8080`:

```
const corsMiddleware = require('restify-cors-middleware');

const cors = corsMiddleware({origins: ['*']});
server.pre(cors.preflight);
server.use(cors.actual);
server.get('/ping', (req, res) => { console.log('pinged'); res.send(200, 'hello') });
```

`CRA on port 3000`:

File `package.json`:

```
"proxy": "http://localhost:8080"
```

File `App.js`:

```
fetch('/ping', { accept: 'application/json' }).then(data => data.json()).then(json => console.log(json));
```

Source: [Here](https://www.fullstackreact.com/articles/using-create-react-app-with-a-server/)